# PHP-jquery-ajax dynamic dependent selection - difficulty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, select

I'm programming a simple form with a dynamic dependent selection. There are two files. One is a php file with html, javascript and php inside, the second is a php file to get data for the second selection and send them back in json format. In the first (and main) file I have the form with two select fields. First field is for province, second is for towns. Data are in a MySQL db, two tables, table_provinces for provinces (103 rows) and table_towns for towns (8000 rows). Normally connect to the db as usual and also link to jquery using a javascript link. First I get provinces options for the first select field, using php to get the values from table_provinces of the db. Then with the javascript " *on('change',function(){ here I use ajax...})* " I pass the selected value using ajax to a php file that might extract towns from table_towns and give back (in json format) values to populate the second select field. Javascript gets correctly the selected value from the first selection field (I used an alert to know it), but nothing more happens. So this is the code.

Link to jquery:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML first select field:

```html
<form method="post" action="usemychoice.php">
<select id="province" name="province" color="white">
<option value="" selected>Select a province</option>
```

This is how I populate the first select field:

```html
 

   <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_provinces"; 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      echo "<option value='".$row['prov']."'>".$row['extended_province']."</option>";

     }

    } else {

     echo "Error: ..........";
    }

    ?>
```

And after closing that field with a  /select  I have this code to get values for populating with town names the second select field:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#province').on('change',function(){
        var provinceID = $(this).val();
        if(provinceID){
         window.alert("ok you've chosen the province "+provinceID);
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'get_towns.php',
                data: 'prov='+provinceID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#town').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#town').html('<option value="">Please select the province first</option>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the get_town.php code:

```html
<?php 


//*****after a require to the connection db routine"


if(!empty($_POST["prov"])) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_towns WHERE prov LIKE '%" .$_POST['prov']."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$json = [];

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     $json[$row['prov']] = $row['town'];

 } else {
    
    echo "Error: .................";
    
    }

echo json_encode($json);

}

?>
```

Finally I have the html code :

```html
<select id="town" name="town" color="white">
<option value="" selected>Select province first</option>
```

At the end of the day, the code has something wrong because I don't get any data back from get_town.php to populate the second select field, and since I didn't see a window.alert that I've put there to check ongoing execution (you don't see it in the code posted here), it seems that is not executed. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
 url:'get_towns.php',
```

Isn't it `get_town.php` without plural ?

Comment: oh yes, just an error while typing here because I changed the names of the towns for this question, not to reveal just actual db configuration  ; )

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it seems that the output of `get_town.php` is JSON

```
echo json_encode($json);
```

but in your JS it is directly output to an html element

```
$('#town').html(html);
```

**Solution:**

Either modify `get_town.php` to send html OR modify the success function in JS to convert received JSON to proper html.

I hope this will help.

**UPDATE:**

Replace this part of php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $json[$row['prov']] = $row['town'];

}
```

with something

```
echo '<option value="" selected>Select Town</option>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo '<option  value="'.$row['town'].'" color="white">'.$row['town'].'</option>';

}
```

and finally remove the line

```
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Thank you Qaisar, how would you suggest to modify the code in both cases?

Comment: I mean, how could be the code to send html from get_town.php or how could be the code to modify success function in javascript to convert the received JSON to proper html

Comment: Tried what you suggest (adding a "</option>") but it does not solve. The second select field doesn't get back anything to be populated with.

Comment: oh, I missed </option> part. Anyhow share the output of `console.log("OUTPUT: " +html);`. Place this above     `$('#town').html(html);` in JS.

Comment: <?php

// ***** after a require to the connection db routine"

if(!empty($_POST["prov"])) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_towns WHERE prov LIKE '%" .$_POST['prov']."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo "<option  value='".$row['town']."'></option>";

 } else {    

            echo "Error:................";    
        }
}

?>

Comment: and still no result

Comment: Try  `data: { 'prov' : provinceID },`  instead of `data: 'prov='+provinceID,` in JS.

Comment: Nope. Any other idea? The fact is that after the call " $.ajax({ ............ " it seems not to be life anywhere in the execution. All is like nothing were neither received nor done by get_town.php

Comment: OK, is there any JS errors in browser's developers tool? 
Is your alert in JS, `window.alert("ok you've chosen the province "+provinceID);` works and display `provinceID` correctly?

Comment: Yes it displays the message and the province. So the problem is after. No errors in browser dev tools.

Comment: Check if get_town.php is accessible, by putting `die( "mmmmmmmmmmmmmm") ;` before `if(!empty($_POST["prov"]))(...`  statement in get_town.php, and `alert(html);` in success function. 

Are both php files in the same directory?

Comment: Tried to intercept status in this way in js script, but nothing happened:
   
all the previous code as before.......
   
                data: 'prov='+provinceID,
                success:function(html){
                    if(response != "") {
                     window.alert("got response");
                    } else {
                     window.alert("no response");
                    }
 
all the rest of the code as before...